# How to understand this behaviour of GeoRange and GeoGraphics

Tags: plotting, geographics

I've preprocessed ~100,000 points in the Vancouver area and am starting to analyze and segment them in different ways. I wanted to start off with a nice finely controllable bounded region since others in the project will have opinions on the viz. I've reduced the code to its basics to reproduce the behaviour. The behaviour is so strange I'm wondering if it's even reproducible by others? I've tried restarting the local Mathematica 12.1 kernal a couple times etc. but the same elongated plot is returned each time.

```
(* Approx. Lower Mainland *)
b = {{49.0, 53.0}, {-123.3, -122.9}}

GeoGraphics[
 GeoRange -> b,
 GeoRangePadding -> None,
 GeoProjection -> Automatic,
 GeoGridLines -> Automatic,
 Frame -> True
 ] 

Options[%, GeoRange]
(* {GeoRange -> {{49., 53.}, {-123.3, -122.9}}} *)
```

[image]

A couple things of note. Firstly, we can confirm the `GeoRange` was applied correctly; and secondly, looking at the image, the longitude was correctly applied but the latitude way overshoots northward. I had a pretty through look at the `GeoRange` [doc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoRange.html), but nothing in the relationship section seemed to apply.

Can someone more familiar with `GeoGraphics` could suggest how they would control the geoplotting region? Or explain the behaviour we're seeing here?

Comment: To cut plot we can use `PlotRange -> {{-123.3, -122.9}, {49.0, 53.0}}`.

Comment: `Options[GeoGraphics, AspectRatio]` evaluates to `{AspectRatio -> Automatic}`. Since you do not prefer this default, add whatever value you want, e.g., `AspectRatio->1`

Comment: having gone through the `GeoRange` docs so recently, the Properties & Relations section mentions another approach using `PlotRange`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

If you want the region around Vancouver you can use that entity for the plot with a selectable `GeoRangePadding`

**EDIT:** Added control for `GeoProjection`

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Manipulate[
 GeoGraphics[
  Entity["City", {"Vancouver", "BritishColumbia", "Canada"}],
  GeoRangePadding -> padding,
  GeoProjection -> projection,
  GeoGridLines -> Automatic,
  Frame -> True],
 Row[{
   Control[
    {{padding, Quantity[50, "km"], "GeoRangePadding"},
     Range[Quantity[0, "km"], Quantity[200, "km"], 
      Quantity[25, "km"]]}],
   Spacer[50],
   Control[
    {{projection, "Equirectangular", 
      "GeoProjection"}, {"Equirectangular", "Mercator"}}]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason the map is elongated is because the boundaries are tall (latitude) and narrow (longitude). To demonstrate the problem, I'll use a function that computes the dimensions of a map from its `GeoRange`.

Here's a function to find map dimensions computed from GeoRange. `mapDimensions` returns:

• latitude distance at west, center, and east of map

• longitude distance at north, center, and south of map

```
mapDimensions[geoRange_?MatrixQ] := Module[{}, {{
    GeoDistance[{#1, {#2[[1]], #1[[2]]}} & @@ Transpose[geoRange]],
    With[{centerLongitude = Mean@Last[geoRange]},
     GeoDistance[{{#1[[1]], centerLongitude}, {#2[[1]], 
          centerLongitude}} & @@
       Transpose[geoRange]]],
    GeoDistance[{{#1[[1]], #2[[2]]}, #2} & @@ 
      Transpose[geoRange]]}, {
    GeoDistance[{{#2[[1]], #1[[2]]}, #2} & @@ Transpose[geoRange]],
    With[{centerLatitude = Mean@First[geoRange]},
     GeoDistance[{{centerLatitude, #1[[2]]}, {centerLatitude, #2[[
           2]]}} & @@
       Transpose[geoRange]]],
    GeoDistance[{#1, {#1[[1]], #2[[2]]}} & @@ Transpose[geoRange]]}}
  ]
```

### Original map

The boundary, `b`, is why the map is elongated. Let's draw a map and get its `GeoRange` from `Options`. The map boundary is ***4° latitude*** by ***0.4° longitude***, or 277 miles by 17 miles, so the map is tall and narrow.

```
b = {{49.0, 53.0}, {-123.3, -122.9}};(*values from question*)
g = GeoGraphics[
   GeoRange -> b,
   GeoRangePadding -> None,
   GeoProjection -> Automatic,
   GeoGridLines -> Automatic
];
(*GeoRange from map*)
geoRange = GeoRange /. Options[g, "GeoRange"]
(*latitude and longitude differences*)
Differences@Transpose@geoRange
(*map dimensions*)
mapDimensions[geoRange]
```

> ```
> {{49., 53.}, {-123.3, -122.9}}
> {{4., 0.4}}
> {{276.506mi, 276.506mi, 276.506mi}, {16.6868mi, 17.4475mi, 18.1867mi}}
> ```

### Map with increased range of longitude

Fix the problem by increasing the range of longitude. Let's keep the same center, but replace the boundary longitudes with 2° west and east of the midpoint. Add a marker at the center of the map.

```
b[[2, All]] = {-2, 2} + Mean@b[[2]];
g = GeoGraphics[GeoMarker[GeoPosition[Mean /@ b]],
  GeoRange -> b,
  GeoRangePadding -> None,
  GeoProjection -> Automatic,
  GeoGridLines -> Automatic
]
```

[image: 4-by-4 degree map]

Now the map is 4° square, or 277 miles by 174 miles.

```
geoRange = GeoRange /. Options[g, "GeoRange"]
Differences@Transpose@geoRange
mapDimensions[geoRange]
```

> ```
> {{49., 53.}, {-125.1, -121.1}}
> {{4., 4.}}
> {{276.506mi, 276.506mi, 276.506mi}, {166.847mi, 174.454mi, 181.846mi}}
> ```

### Map using GeoRange distance

Another way to set map boundaries is to use a distance with `GeoRange` instead of  latitude and longitude boundaries. Let's keep the same center, but use a `GeoRange` distance. `GeoGraphics` computes ranges for latitude and longitude.

```
g = GeoGraphics[GeoMarker[GeoPosition[Mean /@ b]],
  GeoCenter -> Mean /@ b,
  GeoRange -> 
   Quantity[89, "Miles"],(*approximately 4° longitude*)
  GeoRangePadding -> None,
  GeoProjection -> Automatic,
  GeoGridLines -> Automatic
]
```

[image: map using GeoRange with distance]

The map is 178 miles by 178 miles. Notice that the latitude distance is twice the `GeoRange` setting.

```
geoRange = GeoRange /. Options[g, "GeoRange"]
Differences@Transpose@geoRange
mapDimensions[geoRange]
```

> ```
> {{49.7124, 52.2874}, {-125.141, -121.059}}
> {{2.57499, 4.08122}}
> {{178.mi, 178.mi, 178.mi}, {173.024mi, 177.996mi, 182.877mi}}
> ```